# Best way to get ViewContainerRef of mat-row angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a mat-table and now I want to get the ViewContainerRef of clicked row so that I can add another component inside that row. Could you please tell me the best way to get the ViewContainerRef of row.

Currently I am getting it using ViewChildren using myRow as an ID of mat-row.

```
@ViewChildren("myRow", { read: ViewContainerRef }) containers;
```

I am passing index on click of the row.

```
<mat-row #myRow *matRowDef="let row; columns: colInfo;let index=index" 
            (click)="expandRow(index, row)"></mat-row>
```

Based on the index I am fetching the ViewContainerRef like

```
const container = this.containers.toArray()[index];
```

And creating the component like below.

```
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(DetailTableComponent);
const component = container.createComponent(factory);
```

It works fine if I do not do a sorting on the table. As soon as I perform sorting the component is added randomly on different rows because of two reasons
1. Index is updated as soon as I do the sorting (it always set from 0 to n in the order of row)
2. The ViewContainerRef is still having old data i.e. the data before sorting.

If either of the above two issues are resolved then I believe my issue will be resolved.
OR
If I can get the clicked ViewContainerRef then also I believe my problem will be resolved.

Please help.

Comment: Dude!! Exactly same issue m having.. when sorting happens QueryList of ViewContainerRef doesnt update. How did u solve?

Answer (score 0):

I have also been struggling with how to get a particular `ViewContainerRef` from the template. The simplest solution I can think of for you now:

change this

```
expandRow(index, row)
```

to

```
expandRow(index, row, myRow)
```

This is passing myRow as nativeElement.

Then, instead of

```
const container = this.containers.toArray()[index];
```

write

```
const containers = this.containers.toArray();
```

And from there you should be able to do a lookup to find index `i` where

```
containers[i].element.nativeElement === myRow
```